# kTag value. What is the recommended range?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I am using tags to access/manipulate UIViews as follows:

(in this instance, the code is in a UIView+Category)

```
#define kTagButton 60000

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
    ...
    [myButton setTag:kTagButton];
    [self addSubview:myButton];
}

- (void)removeButton {
    UIButton *someButton = (UIButton*)[self.viewWithTag:kTagButton];
    [someButton removeFromSuperView];
}
```

My question is:
what is the recommended range of values to use for the tags?
I vaguely remember reading that the lowest values were reserved for internal tasks.

Thank you.

Comment: Documentation isn't great on this. But it wouldn't seem like a good idea for apple to implement it like you say remember reading. Otherwise you could break internals just by tagging views with anything. That isn't to say you're wrong...